# How can I get the sum of a count in SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to get the sum of a count (id)
So total numeric value of the total counts

Tried running the query below but error appeared

```
SELECT sum(count(id))) as Transactions,DATE_TRUNC(created_at,ISOWEEK) AS Week, payment.status,
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY 2,3
HAVING payment.status="failed" OR payment.status="cancelled"
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: AGREGATIONS OF AGREGATIONS NOT ALLOWED

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be with a WHERE CLAUSE since HAVING is for aggregated functions? You also had a comma after payment.status which would cause an error.

```
SELECT sum(count(id))) as Transactions,DATE_TRUNC(created_at,ISOWEEK) AS Week, payment.status
FROM TABLE
WHERE (payment.status="failed" OR payment.status="cancelled")        
GROUP BY 2,3
ORDER by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Avoid the error you get : AGREGATIONS OF AGREGATIONS NOT ALLOWED

You can re-write your query as :

```
SELECT 
  SUM(cnt) AS Transactions,
  DATE_TRUNC(created_at, ISOWEEK) AS Week,
  payment.status
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS cnt,
    created_at,
    payment.status
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE payment.status = 'failed' OR payment.status = 'cancelled'
  GROUP BY 2,3
) t
GROUP BY 2,3
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```